# How to force hcitool scan

Tags: bluetooth, reset, hci

I'm using hcitool to discover BT devices.

```
hcitool scan
```

I works great but when it succeeds, the successive invocations will return the contents of the discovery cache and return immediately. I need a way to force the scanning to make sure I always get the most up to date presence info. One solution I found is

```
hciconfig reset
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hcitool's scan command has it's own help. If you type:

```
hcitool scan --help
```

you get:

```
# hcitool scan --help
Usage:
    scan [--length=N] [--numrsp=N] [--iac=lap] [--flush] [--class] [--info] [--oui] [--refresh]
```

I've had a hard time finding further documentation on each of these options, but I've found that the "--flush" option doesn't seem to use the cache:

```
hcitool --flush
```

Comment: hcitool scan --flush works. Thanks.